# Batch update thousads of SQL rows using c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I need to update tens of thousands rows in SQL table row-after-row. How is it possible to speed-up this scenario by some `batch update` or semething? We use SQL Server 2008.

**Edit**: I need to update rows (issue SQL) from `C#` not from the stored procedure because the logic is complicated. I need to, let's say, "retest" each row individually.

**Edit2**: We need to "update" whole table (each row). Is it possible to load table by chunks, update them in memory and save back to the database??? How in C#?

Comment: How are you currently performing this task? Are you using a cursor or some other RBAR method? Or is your query set-based yet simply performing poorly? Also, describe what you are attempting to accomplish (monthly reconciliation of payments marks all accounts as settled when the debits and credits net out) and give us some idea of what the tables look like

Comment: please be more specific, for instance, why do you need to update "row-after-row"? is there sequential business logic at work here?

Comment: The whole point of SQL is to do operations in sets rather than row-after-row.

Comment: We need to "retest" each row and update it. Logic is complicated and involves not only the database.

Comment: Can you test them all in a batch? If not, the best performance you are going to get is row by agonizing row. Also, that's not what a database is for.

Comment: What determines when a row needs to be retested? Do you re-test all the rows at once or is there some criteria for determining what's dirty?

Comment: Yes, they can be tested in batch. But can one "Load 1000 rows, update them in memory and store them back?" (how in C#?) Whole table will be retested/updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many assumptions here, but what about creating a [user defined table type](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2010/06/t-sql-tuesday-007-summertime-in-sql.html) and within your business layer, populate that in-memory table with *all* the rows that need updated at once and then call a proc that does a proper, set-based update.

```
CREATE PROC dbo.RBARBane(@tvp dbo.MyUserDefinedTableType)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE
        T
    SET
        col1 = TVP.col1
        -- all the columns that need updated
    FROM
        dbo.Table T
        INNER JOIN
            @tvp TVP
            ON TVP.key1 = T.key1
END
```

Comment: But the logic needs to be in C#, it will be called from WCF. How then? We are calling update from WCF and the main logic is in WCF (C#).

Comment: Being ignorant of WCF, but not C#, does WCF not allow for creating and calling a SqlCommand stored proc?  Look at the bottom of the linked article, it has a reference C# invocation section.

Comment: Yes, it's obvious now. Simply load table from Database, update it in C# and call the stored procedure with the updated table as parameter, right?

Answer (score -1):

- Temporary disable triggers
- Temporary drop indexes
- update fewer records in a loop to reduce locking

Comment: This was just a guess for batch updating. I think you should write more about your needs as the commenters suggest. And you should measure what part of the update took most time before trying to optimize.

Comment: i think this is a red herring.  your basic problem is that you need to visit every row and perform 'complicated' tests on it, then post.  this will not be improved by trying to reduce these overheads.

Comment: @Randy: It depends. Maybe there is an update trigger which took 500ms per row to execute. So its all a guess without more info